# Finding particulair solution to $y''-3y'+2y = \cos 2x + \sin x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''-3y'+2y = \cos 2x + \sin x$$

To find the particulair solution to this problem I divide it to two subproblems:
$y_p = u_p + v_p$

I then apply $u = A \sin 2x + B \cos 2x = \cos 2x$ and $v = A \sin x + B \cos x = \sin x$

As the accepted answer in [solve $y''-2y'-y=\sin{3x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816925/solve-y-2y-y-sin3x)

However, $$u = A \sin 2x + B \cos 2x = \cos 2x$$ gives me http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%27%27-3u%27%2B2u%3Dcos2x the answer should be $$\frac{1}{10} \left(\cos2x-2\sin 2x\right)$$

$v = A \sin x + B \cos x = \sin x$ on the hand gives me $v_p = 0$ when I do the math (which should be correct) but https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%27%27-3u%27%2B2u%3Dsinx

Where do I fail? This doesn't seem to be a simple calculation error.

Comment: I got the same solution as W|A did. Perhaps, the 'correct' answer in your textbook is wrong.

Comment: That is of course possible, but I get this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%E2%80%B2%E2%80%B2%E2%88%923y%E2%80%B2%2B2y%3Dcos2x%2Bsinx

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to plug in $u_p'$ and $u_p''$ into the original equation and equate to the entire right-hand side $\cos 2x + \sin x$. Otherwise, you won't get the whole solution.
$$u_p=A \sin(2x)+B\cos(2x)$$
$$u_p'=2A\cos(2x)-2B\sin(2x)$$
$$u_p''=-4A\sin(2x)-4B\cos(2x)$$
Plug into original equation:
$$(-4A\sin(2x)-4B\cos(2x))-3(2A\cos(2x)-2B\sin(2x))+2(A \sin(2x)+B\cos(2x))=\cos(2x)+\sin(x)$$
Expand:
$$\sin(2x)(-4A+6B+2A)=\sin(2x)(1)$$
$$\cos(2x)(-4B-6A+2B)=\cos(2x)(1)$$
Simplify:
$$(-2A+6B)=1$$
$$(-6A-2B)=1$$
Solving for $A$, $B$:
$$A=-\frac{1}{5}, B=\frac{1}{10}$$
Plug into the assumed particular solution gives exactly what we expect:
$$u_p=-\frac{1}{5}\sin(x)+\frac{1}{10}\cos(2x)$$
$$u_p=\frac{1}{10}(\cos(2x)-2\sin(x))$$

Comment: But the missing part of the solution should be in $v_p$

Comment: Yeah, sorry, was writing quickly. Will edit the post.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer. However it's wrong (I think) you can't compare $\sin (2x) = \sin (x) $ like you do. However this made me study the question even harder and find that I wrote it wrong (it really should be 2x everywhere). So I was solving the wrong question, that's why the solution got wrong.